# can't change LEDs states using PCA9685

Tags: led, driver, rgb, code

I have a PCA9685 IC connected to i2c of cubieboard like board. Also OE pin is connected to one GPIO pin. I'm using `ic2tools` to communicate with PCA9685, I can read/write to registers without any problems, but changes I do to registers does not take effect, LEDs don't change them state.

There are 4 RGB leds connected through a resistor to PCA9685 (as Fig 15 of PCA9685 datasheet), this is, 12 channels are being used. Doesn't matter which value I write to PWM registers, LEDs state are always the same, oddly, colors are not equal to each LED. 1 LED has red, 1 LED has blue, 1 magenta and 1 white. However, colors are not random, always I turn off/on PCA9685 the same colors are assumed by the same LEDs.

I can switch all LEDs on/off by changing OE pin state.

Here is the code I'm using to test.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

PCA9685_BUS=1
PCA9685_ADDR=0x41
PCA9685_OE="pi15"

# config GPIO as output and set initial state
${PWD}/gpio_config.sh "$PCA9685_OE" "out" "1"

# set output logic as inverted
i2cset -y $PCA9685_BUS $PCA9685_ADDR 0x01 0x10

# restart
i2cset -y $PCA9685_BUS $PCA9685_ADDR 0x00 0x91
sleep 1

# change to normal mode
i2cset -y $PCA9685_BUS $PCA9685_ADDR 0x00 0x01
sleep 1

for (( i = 0x06; i <= 0x45; i++ )); do
    i2cset -y $PCA9685_BUS $PCA9685_ADDR $i 0x0F
done
```

Running `i2cdump` I can see registers were changed.

```
[root@board test]# i2cdump 1 0x41
No size specified (using byte-data access)
WARNING! This program can confuse your I2C bus, cause data loss and worse!
I will probe file /dev/i2c-1, address 0x41, mode byte
Continue? [Y/n] 
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: 01 10 e2 e4 e8 e0 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f    ????????????????
10: 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f    ????????????????
20: 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f    ????????????????
30: 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f    ????????????????
40: 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f 0f XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    ??????XXXXXXXXXX
50: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
60: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
70: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
80: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
90: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
a0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
b0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
c0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
d0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
e0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
f0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 1e 00    XXXXXXXXXX....?.
```

I've tried others values than 0x0F, same issue.

Any idea over what can be happening?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, any updates on this? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Tiago the colors problem was hardware, bad pins connection.